# Attribute Not Being Added to Object

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, object, attributes

I'm trying to add an attribute to a model object. Direct access works but when I print the entire object or encode it into JSON, that attribute is left out. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my rails console output:

```
irb(main):010:0> b=ChatMessage.new(:user_id=>4,:room_id=>1,:message=>"Hello World")
=> #<ChatMessage id: nil, room_id: 1, user_id: 4, message: "Hello World", created_at:     nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):011:0> b.sender_nickname="bbb"
=> "bbb"
irb(main):012:0> b.sender_nickname
=> "bbb"
irb(main):013:0> b
=> #<ChatMessage id: nil, room_id: 1, user_id: 4, message: "Hello World", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Here is my model code:

```
class ChatMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :sender_nickname

  def self.get_last_message_id
    last_message=ChatMessage.all.last
    last_message.nil? ? 0 : last_message.id
  end

  def self.get_all_messages_after(room_id,message_id)
    ChatMessage.where("room_id = ? AND id > ?",room_id,message_id)
  end
end
```

edit:

Here is the migration file for chat_messages table.
I'm not really looking to save sender_nickname. So it's more like a virtual attribute (but is still in db through association). And I might need to add other attributes later that aren't in the db. Is it possible to do it without using association?

```
def self.up
  create_table :chat_messages do |t|
    t.integer :room_id
    t.integer :user_id
    t.string :message

    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

Comment: Does your `ChatMessage` model at first have sender_nickname as an attribute? Otherwise, it won't be able to save `sender_nickname` attribute.

Comment: I'm not trying to save it. sender_nickname is like a virtual attribute that I dont want in my database. I only want it in the JSON i render.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll include my db schema anyway, along with an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I know **to_json** will only take the attributes in the model and serialize (as in chat_message.attributes, not attr_accessor).

You properbly got a sender, or user model, or anything like that.

What I would do is to make a relation to the sender, user or what its called, with a belong_to, and then use this code to convert it to json:

```
chat_message.to_json(:include => { :sender => { :only => :nickname } })
```

It may also work with you code, and then just:

```
chat_message.to_json(:include => { :sender_nickname })
```

There also some documentation here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was told that I should not use to_json, but instead use ActiveSupport::JSON.encode, but that would probably work with association too. For the sake of the question though, is it possible to do it without association? I might need to add non-database attributes later.

Comment: Hi Max, I'm not sure. Does it work with the last of the code examples?

Comment: Hi Jesper. That work! Thanks! This is what I did: ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(new_messages,:include=>{:user=>{:only => :nickname}}) thought I'm still curious what to do if I need to include stuff that isn't in db. I guess I'll try look that up first.